# Plotting self-made predictions and prediction intervals in the same format as autoplot for auto.arima

Tags: r, plot, forecasting

I have some forecasts for a range of time-series calculated using the `auto.arima()` function. I plot these using either `autoplot()` or `plot()` functions.

However, I have - for purely illustrative purposes - created some forecasts data-series with predictions intervals and I want to plot them to look exactly the same as the `autoplot()` or `plot()` graphs.

Anyone know how this can be done? I assume one can find the code behind the two plot functions somewhere, and then simply insert my self-constructed prediction intervals and forecasts

Comment: you can find the source code with `getAnywhere(autoplot.zoo)`

Comment: @ThinkR thanks for the response. I don't however seem to be able to understand the code, that comes up using that command.